# Primary key violation does not raise error in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

I am using PHP with `sqlsrv_query` and have an issue where an SQL error is not... causing an error.

For example, this code where user_id 1 already exists

```
$sqlresult = sqlsrv_query($db_conn, "INSERT into dbo.users( user_id, name)
                VALUES( 1, 'Adam');");
if( $sqlResult === false ) {
    echo "\nSQL result indicated a failure\n";
    die(  print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

$sqlresult is not false, despite the sql query failing with a primary key violation.

SQL Studio shows the following

```
Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 2
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_users'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.users'. The duplicate key value is (1).
The statement has been terminated.
```

If i try the INSERT with a bad data type, i.e 'xyz' for the user_id, I do not see "The statement has been terminated.". And if executed from PHP, $sqlresult is correctly false.

The primary key violation needs to be fixed, but I am concerned that certain 'types' of errors are being silently ignored.

Any ideas why one type of error is treated differently over another?

Comment: I think this has to do something with the used driver. `sqlsrv_query` doesn't appear on the PHP manual which means it's not an official library or driver by PHP. Which makes the developer of the library and/or driver responsible.

Comment: I can imagine. But perhaps there is a clue in the way sql studio returns "Statement terminated" with a PK violation error, but not data type errors?

Comment: I've actually just implemented a new table, and found the PK violation correctly returning $sqlresult as false. So i dunno whats going on, i'd have to go back and investigate.

Answer (score 1):

The `user_id` column may be a primary key in `dbo.users` tables. Hence its not accepting duplicate values.

There are multiple ways of handling this issue.

1. Make sure the `user_id` is not present in the table. something like
   `MAX(user_id) + 1`.
2. Make `user_id` column as AUTOINCREMENT, so that you dont have to worry about the next ID and change you insert query like this
   `INSERT into dbo.users(name) VALUES('Adam')`

I would prefer to implement in the 2nd way(with the AUTOINCREMENT), which is more cleaner approach.

Comment: In drupal hook_schema type "serial" is used  to get AUTOINCREMENT in database.for example```'user_id' => array(
        'description' => 'user_id',
        'type' => 'serial',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
      )```

Comment: SQL Server has not `AUTOINCREMENT`, you can use `IDENTITY` or `SEQUENCE` if needed.